# mysql dump restore with privileges issue

Tags: permissions, mysql

I created a sql dump using mysql dump but on restoring on another server I get an error `'ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 397: Access denied; you need the SUPER privilege for                                                                                         this operation :`

when i checked the line number I see the issue seems to be with part root`@`localhost, as new server does not have root privileges from the account I am using. If i removed root`@`localhost it went ahead but I am not sure if its right way by removing root`@`localhost from the following as there are many places in the sql file it has the reference.
What would be the right way?

```
/*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50017 DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`*/ /*!50003 TRIGGER `Update Feeback status in Order` AFTER INSERT ON `customer_ratings`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
```

Comment: Do you change datadir on your MySQL Server? Is it for windows?

Answer (score 0):

Fist you can check your access.

1.- Check for your access in the new server

$mysql -u root -p -hlocalhost

Enter password:

2.- show your grants

$mysql>SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';

To solve the problem you can do this.

1.- stop your services.

service mysqld stop

2.- start your services with "stop grant tables"

mysqld --skip-grant-tables

3.-update the password of user root

$mysql>UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('my_password') where USER='root';

(if you want you can create your user)
$mysql>CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

4.- Flush the privilages

$mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

5.- Restart your server

service mysqld start

6.- tray to restore your dump file.

mysql -u root -hlocalhost -p [database_name] < dumpfilename.sql

Hope this help.

Comment: I dont have root privileges on the mysql so I want to know if i remove this part /*!50017 DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`*/ from mysql sql file and restore will i cause any issue on functioning of triggers created as I have seen if i remove /*!50017 DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`*/ it creates db from restore sql file

Comment: trigger is created after removing the like as I mentioned above.    Trigger: Insert for Category Count
               Event: INSERT
               Table: gc_categories
           Statement: BEGIN
   INSERT INTO gc_category_counts SET category_id = new.id;
END
              Timing: AFTER
             Created: NULL
            sql_mode: NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO
             Definer: hart@%
character_set_client: utf8
collation_connection: utf8_general_ci
  Database Collation: utf8_general_ci

Comment: The DEFINER clause determines the security context to be used when checking access privileges at trigger activation time. It was added in MySQL 5.0.17.  

What version you have in your old and new MySQL server? @user1492502

Comment: Note: You can read about this in:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html